# Issue aspx bootstrap

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2015, bootstrap-4

I have a little problem with my project. I'm working with aspx dot net and bootstrap to make it beauty, buuuuuut out of nowhere my page started to show only a white page. The curious thing is that I can interact with the objects in the page, like some textboxes and buttons, but still nothing appears on the screen.

I try making a new project and creating a new simple page (using bootstrap too) but the same thing happened.
I have another site, and run perfectly without bootstrap.
I've already downloaded it again and making a new reference... 
The IIS process didn't show anything about this...
Do you know what can I do about this...?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There  could be only one reason i.e you have not included the correct references.

Comment: But this happened from nowhere... 'till one hour ago the site ran perfect...

Comment: Inspect element and determine if what you are seeing matches the computed style and if so why is it computing out like that. Open your browser's dev tools and look for 404's or other failed requests for CSS files.

Comment: Are you using a CDN (external URL) for Bootstrap?

Comment: I copy the references from another project and then it star working... I must touch something in the head section and didn't notice... Thank you guys!